# remove an item form levels of pivot data frame at pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I made a pivot dataframe at pandas and it's columns are separated in two levels
How can I remove the first level?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
% matplotlib inline
df=pd.read_csv('file01.csv')
grouped_df=df.groupby(['neighborhood','bedrooms'],as_index= False).mean().round()
pivot_df=grouped_df.pivot(index='bedrooms',columns='neighborhood')
pivot_df.columns
```

the result

```
MultiIndex(levels=[['price'], ['ANDON', 'ANTIBES', 'ASCROS', 'ASPREMONT', 'AURIBEAU-SUR-SIAGNE']])
```

I want to remove ['price'] because when I want to filter the picot_dataframe it shows this error

```
pivot_df['ANDON','ANTIBES']
```

the error

```
KeyError: ('ANDON', 'ANTIBES')
```